# Bash curl returns 0 whenever the copy has finished or not

Tags: bash, curl

I'm calling curl on bash to copy a file from a mounted SD card with the option to resume the copy later if the device gets unmounted. I receive the same status exit code 0 when I interrupt the copy by unmounting the volume and when the file gets actually copied. Any suggestions how to catch the case where the file has not been copied?

I'm copying only one file at a time.

This is the command:

```
curl -C - -O file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100/0044.MP4
```

Comment: Better use `rsync`. And are you copying more than one file? Please update your post with further details.

Comment: Thank you, updated! I'm copying only one file at a time. I want to catch the return from the unsuccessful copy so I can resume on the next mount of the card.

Comment: I just tried "rsync -av --no-compress" and it is not working for me. During file copy I unmount the volume and rsync continues showing progress of the copy on screen. The exception comes very late.

Answer (score 1):

I came to a solution which is not as clear as I want, but still working. I'm executing the command 2 times one after another, so when the first command returns 0 upon unmount, the second now tries to copy the file and return error code 37 because of the unreachable source. If the second command returns 0 I consider the file copied.

Answer (score 1):

Following your concept you could have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copies files persistently.
#
# Usage: pc <filepath> [<filepath2>] ...
#
function pc {
    local FILE
    for FILE; do
        echo "Copying $FILE."
        until curl -C - -O "file://${FILE}" && curl -C - -O "file://${FILE}"; do
            if [[ -e $FILE ]]; then
                echo "File $FILE can't be copied."
                break
            else
                echo "Waiting for $FILE."
                until
                    sleep 5
                    [[ -e $FILE ]]
                do
                    continue
                done
            fi
        done
    done
}

pc "$@"
```

You could also just embed the function to a bash startup script if you like.